# Using Vue Components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, vue.js

I have a project that is built in Vue and I want to reuse the components from the Vue application in an Angular application so I don't have to go and rebuild every single component from scratch.

I saw this tutorial on medium: [How to use Vue 2.0 components in an angular application](https://medium.com/@graphicbeacon/how-to-use-vue-2-0-components-in-an-angular-application-4d85bacc42dc), but that tutorial is for AngularJS.

I'm wondering if anyone has done this before, if it's worth it and if anyone knows of any tutorials or reference material.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Wrap your Vue components as [native **Web Components**](https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction).

Since Angular supports using custom Web Components, you'll be able to use the Vue components (wrapped as Web Components).

To Angular it doesn't make a difference if the custom Web Components were generated by Vue or not (for all Angular knows, they could be native HTML elements).

## Demo

[**Runnable DEMO here.**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjp53l?file=index.html)

The demo is an Angular 5 app. The Vue custom component is defined in [`index.html`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjp53l?file=index.html). Notice how in [`app/app.component.html`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjp53l?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) it is used directly in the template, as if it were a native element.

Step by step below.

## In Vue

Use [`vue-custom-element`](https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element) to wrap your Vue components as Web Components:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-custom-element@3.0.0/dist/vue-custom-element.js"></script>
<script>
  const MyVueWebComp = {
    props: ['msg'],
    template:`
    <div style="border: 3px dashed green; padding: 5px">
      I am my-vue-web-comp.<br>
      Value of "msg" prop: {{ msg }}<br>
      <input v-model="text"><button @click="addText">Click me</button>
      <div v-for="t in texts">
        Text: {{ t }}
      </div>
    </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
            text: '',
            texts: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
      addText() {
        this.texts.push(this.text);
        this.text = '';
      }
    }
  };
  Vue.customElement('my-vue-web-comp', MyVueWebComp);
</script>
```

That will create a `<my-vue-web-comp>` web component that can be used directly in the DOM, **without** the need to have a working Vue instance.

The above is just a demo runnable directly in the browser. If you have **.vue** files and a vue-cli app, you'll need to do `npm install vue-custom-element --save` and then create a `.js` file like:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import vueCustomElement from 'vue-custom-element';
import MyElement from './MyElement.vue';

Vue.use(vueCustomElement);
Vue.customElement('my-element', MyElement);
```

And then this, when bundled, will generate a `.js` file that can be imported directly as a single `<script>` tag, **instead of the whole code and script tags above**.

For more details, check [`vue-custom-element`'s docs](https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element).

## In Angular

Now, in the Angular app, after importing the Web Components (being them Vue-generated or not), [configure them to be used by Angular](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule#schemas) by adding `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` in your `@NgModule`:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

//...

@NgModule({
  // ...
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA  // added this
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
```

Now use the Web Components (generated from Vue or not) directly in Angular templates. E.g. the component defined in the code above could be used like:

```
<my-vue-web-comp [msg]="name"></my-vue-web-comp>
```

In fact, the runnable demo [**shows an example of that usage.**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjp53l?file=index.html)

## Limitations

You may need polyfills for older browser support. Please check [`vue-custom-element`'s docs](https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element) for more details.

Comment: Another limitation or requirement would be webcomponents are supported in Angular 1.7 and higher :/

Comment: How can I use it for dynamic prop in runtime ([msg]="{{ messageInfo.MsgTxt }}") ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68986638/set-property-dynamically-in-vue-component-for-angular

Comment: The provided demo appears to be broken.
"Error: Vue.customElement is not a function"

Comment: What if the vuejs component comes from a npm package?

Comment: I don't think it matters if the vuejs component is locally defined or imported from another npm package