# How to create Web-component in Vue+typescript for Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js, web-component

I use [vue-custom-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724029/using-vue-components-in-angular/49724561#49724561) to create Web-component in Vue and use it in Angular.
It works fine for Vue+js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Calculator from './components/Calculator.vue'

import vueCustomElement from 'vue-custom-element'

Vue.use(vueCustomElement)
Vue.customElement('js-calculator', Calculator)
```

and I use in Angular at index.html:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <js-calculator msg="30"></js-calculator>
</body>
```

It works fine. But when I use typescript and [vue-class-component](https://class-component.vuejs.org/) in Vue (instead of javascript) and the same code, I don't see web-component in Angular. Vue+ts calculator works in a separate app too. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer:

On typescript instead of

```
Vue.customElement('ts-calculator', Calculator)
```

we should use

```
Vue.customElement('ts-calculator', (Calculator as any).options)
```

or

```
Vue.customElement('ts-calculator', new Calculator().$options)
```