# Set property dynamically in Vue component for angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, vue.js, web-component

I read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724029/using-vue-components-in-angular/49724561) and created web-component:

```
<my-vue-web-comp [userId]="1"></my-vue-web-comp>
```

It works fine in Angular when I set static prop. But when I try to set property dynamically:

```
<my-vue-web-comp [userId]="{{ usersInfo.userId }}"></my-vue-web-comp>
```

my property userId is empty in web-component. It looks like the web component is being converted at compiling and not at runtime.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think in Angular you can only do this

```html
<my-vue-web-comp [userId]="usersInfo.userId"></my-vue-web-comp>
```

or this

```html
<my-vue-web-comp userId="{{ usersInfo.userId }}"></my-vue-web-comp>
```

if both do not work try this

```html
<my-vue-web-comp user-id="{{ usersInfo.userId }}"></my-vue-web-comp>
```