# Detect mounting of web-component in DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, vue.js, web-component

I read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724029/using-vue-components-in-angular/49724561) created web-component:

```
<my-vue-web-comp [userId]="1" id="my-component"></my-vue-web-comp>
```

It works fine in Angular. How can I detect when web component was mounted in DOM?

In this code I get null:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const myComponent = document.getElementById('my-component')
  console.log(myComponent) //null
}
```

In this code I get my component, but I should wait 0.5 sec:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        setTimeout(
            function() {
                const myComponent = document.getElementById('my-component')
                console.log(myComponent) //not null                
            }, 500)
    }
```

Is there any tool (event) to detect mounting of web-component in DOM ?

Comment: I guess your webcomponent could simply fire a customEvent on a top level element? Your Angular app can listen to that event.

Comment: @MikeOne yes, I can call the function from my web-component, but how can I detect when it was mounted in Angular's web app DOM ?

Comment: IMHO you are learning Web Components in the wrong order. You are now learning Tool syntax first, before you learn the core Technology. My advice, learn to develop (basic) vanilla JavaScript Web Components first. After that select a Tool to speed up development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add **connectedCallback()** from the [docs](https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element):

```
Vue.customElement('web-component', (MyWebComponent as any).options, { connectedCallback() {
      console.info('connectedCallback', this)
    }})
```