# share a source where there is detailed explanation on how to use vueJS web-component in angular App

Tags: angular, vue-component

I've searched on various sources for this, nothing is providing the detailed info in it. please share me one. I would appreciate if its a detailed video link.

I've no idea how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Vue Components in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724029/using-vue-components-in-angular)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it possible to change vueJS-component into npm package and use it in angular app?
If yes, Please provide me a source.

Comment: I've created VueJS-component into npm package, Here's the link:
`https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-test-npmm`

I am able to use it in another VueJS project, but I want to use in angular app. Please suggest how to do it?