# How to use Vue Components in Angular application

Tags: angular, vue.js, custom-element

I have a Angular application. all the apps in our org is in Angular, Our Vue js app is outdated, and its very big, instead of migrating from VUe 2 to Vue 3, we thought lets write everything Aangular, I came up with a thought, to re write the Vue components in Angular to see if that possible.

Researching it online I found that `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` in the app.module.ts will allow any html tag to be used and vue-custom-element will allow to use the custome elements, Reference(https://www.ais.com/using-a-vue-component-in-an-angular-app/). Everywhere I see only one component being used. what if there are multiple Vue components that I want to use in my Application.

The above example though did not work for me. Can some some one help me knowing how to work on this ?

I used this approach, but it did not work for me.

[Using Vue Components in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724029/using-vue-components-in-angular)

Reference links:
https://dev.to/ippatev/how-to-use-the-vue-component-in-an-angular-project-2ag4
https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element#demo

Comment: What's the point of rewriting to angular if you're just going to import old existing vue components?

Comment: the old project was in Vue 2.0, migration from 2 to 3 is a big process and time taking process, and in our org, we do not have Vue stack in any of our projects. required components to Angular and eventually converting everything to Angular is the ultimate goal