# How to integerate a vue app in a angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js, vuejs3, angular13

Hi guys I have a navbar which is written in vuejs and i have 7 apps in which 4 is written in vanila js and 3 is written in angular.Found a way to integrate in vanila but  now for i want to integrate the navbar in angular but i don't know how to integrate it.
Is it possible?

Found this in which they provide a single component but mine has more than 100 components and some dependencies like material-ui,vuetify.Will it work.

Found this link:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724029/using-vue-components-in-angular](https://stackoverflow.com)

This is for a single component

and tried this but [https://www.ais.com/using-a-vue-component-in-an-angular-app/](https://stackoverflow.com)

but in vue3 got this

**ERROR  Vue 3 support of the web component target is still under development.
**
And we are using angular13

Comment: " vue3 got this" - you get this in vue cli which isn't mentioned in the question, not in vue. The problem is specific to your setup. You can switch to vite and stick to WC, or you can make it the way it would be done in any framework combo, i.e. bundle nested apps, import them inside another framework and mount them to dom elements

Comment: is there are any reference or example for the above and my app is already using vite?

Comment: Something like this https://passage.1password.com/post/developing-web-components-with-vue . As for the second option, it's just doing `myVueApp.mount(someNgContainerElement)` inside Angular comp instead of doing app.mount('#root') inside vue app

Comment: Found the solution:https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#using-custom-elements-in-vue